# Как отделить буквы от чисел в строке? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Пример: из этого 6S3H1E9U2V0W8L4A4 , надо превратить в это 631920844
Желательно с применением регулярных выражений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re # Импорт модуля для работы с регулярными выражениями 

string = "6S3H1E9U2V0W8L4A4" # Данные

def numbers_from_string(data):                 # Функция берёт строку
    result = "".join(re.findall(r'\d+', data)) # находит все числа в строке и склеивает их в строку 
    return result                              # возвращает полученный результат

def main():
    print(numbers_from_string(string))         # Вызов функции и печать результата

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А почему вот так нельзя: 
import re

string = input()

def numbers_from_string(data):
    result = "".join(re.findall(r'\d+', data))
    return result

print(numbers_from_string(string))

Comment: Можно и через input() данные вводить

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения#Символьные_классы_(наборы_символов)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B_(%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2))

```
import re
s = "Exam123ple String"
replaced = re.sub('[\D]', '', s)
print replaced
```

Comment: Зачем замена символов?

Comment: @mkkik пример не до конца отредактирвал. Ща норм вариант

Comment: Квадратные скобки вроде лишние.

Comment: @Qwertiy , это кому как нравится

Answer (score -1):

Вот такое решение кажется более полным, поскольку в итоге получим список из раздельных значений, а не просто строку из цифр.

```
import re
result_list = re.findall(r'\d+', example_str)
```